Flutter Build Failed with JdkImageTransform Error during :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
I'm a beginner in Flutter and I'm facing an issue while trying to build my app. Here is the error message I encountered:
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /home/user-name/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /opt/android-studio/jbr/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /home/user-name/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9263d05e7a9236c2cfa2ca39c5a20e5a/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /home/user-name/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9263d05e7a9236c2cfa2ca39c5a20e5a/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


here my flutter doctor:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS 6.8.0-45-generic,
    locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources



What I've tried so far:

Set JAVA_HOME to Java 17 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64) and verified it with java -version.
Change Android Studio Ladybug into koala ( same error appear ).
Cleared the Gradle cache using ./gradlew clean and flutter clean, but the issue persists.
Reinstalled Android SDK platform 34 using the Android Studio SDK Manager.

Despite these efforts, I keep running into this error when building the app. I'm not sure what else to try and would really appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to fix this issue.
Additional Info:
Flutter version: 3.24
Java version: OpenJDK 17
Android Studio version: Android Studio Ladybug
OS: Ubuntu 24

error spsific solutions

Did you open the only "android" folder of your flutter project with Android Studio and let the IDE automatically download and install the gradle?

@saman I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and just running the project in debug mode. I still keep running into these errors. Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

@saman I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and was running the project in debug mode. The previous errors are gone now, but I'm seeing this warning: "Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times." Right now, I'm using Android Studio Koala.

If you use Android Studio instead of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, after opening the "android" folder of your project, it would take care of gradle building in your project and make life much easier for Flutter developers.

@saman I've looked into several sources, such as this Stack Overflow thread, and many recommend updating the Gradle or using the latest SDK tools via terminal commands. However, after checking, I found that my SDK tools are already up-to-date. Regarding the Gradle update, I've also searched through the folder but couldn't find the 'classpath' that needs modification. Any further guidance on this would be appreciated!

If you open the "android" folder of your flutter project with Android Studio and after building gradle, it may show you some error messages in build section. that messages would be useful for community to help you solve the problem

You can try the following steps to resolve the build issue:

Navigate to the android directory and run this command to update the Gradle version:
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version latest

Update the android/settings.gradle by modifying it like this:


id "com.android.application" version "8.7.0" apply false


Update the NDK version in android/app/build.gradle by adding or changing this line:

ndkVersion = "27.0.12077973"

Reference for details : answer

Already solved my problem! I found this GitHub issue. So basically, the problem occurred when the bundled JDK version and the Gradle settings were not compatible with each other. Ensuring that the sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility in app/build.gradle were set to Java 17, along with the correct Kotlin and Gradle versions, resolved the issues I was facing. I appreciate all the help and insights from the community!

Try this (set your jdk path):
flutter config --jdk-dir "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home"


This worked for me
Basically, you need this in app\build.gradle:
compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
  jvmTarget = 17
}

This in settings.gradle:
id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false

And this in gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip

